# Lee Smooth Manifolds Problem 1-11 - $\overline{\mathbb B}^n$ is a smooth manifold with boundary

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

The following is Problem 1-11 in Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*, 2nd Edition:

> Let $M = \overline{\mathbb B}^n$, the closed unit ball in $\mathbb R^n$. Show that $M$ is a topological manifold with boundary in which each point in $\mathbb S^{n - 1}$ is a boundary point and each point in $\mathbb B^n$ is an interior point. Show how to give it a smooth structure such that every smooth interior chart is a smooth chart for the standard smooth structure on $\mathbb B^n$.[Hint: consider the map $\pi \circ \sigma^{-1}: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$, where $\sigma : \mathbb S^n \to \mathbb R^n$ is the stereographic projection and $\pi$ is a projection from $\mathbb R^{n + 1}$ to $\mathbb R^n$ that omits some coordinate other than the last.]

So, for the first part of the question I proceeded as follows:

> It is clear that for each point in $\mathbb B^n$ there is a ball $B$ of small radius such that $(B, Id + (0, \ldots, 0, 1))$ is a coordinate chart onto $\text{Int} \mathbb H^n$. So each point in $\mathbb B^n$ is an interior point.

Now, how to show the other two claims? How to use the hint?

Thanks in advance and kind regards.

Comment: I post my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2313700/showing-that-bar-mathbbbn-is-a-manifold-with-boundary-lee-itm-probelm-3/2755562#2755562). It's a bit long and tedious, but i hope that will help.

Comment: @SiKucing, thank you very much, I understand now.

Comment: You're welcome.